# Can't unset session during paypal ipn response

Tags: php, session, paypal-ipn, unset

I need to unset my session variables, when PayPal returns IPN.

The simplest script is the following

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['my_item']);
?>
```

Paypal sends IPN, all works fine, but after request my session variable save it's value.

What can be a problem?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

As mentioned, when ipn sends request, it's already another session, so i can do the following.

Before send user to paypal, set custom variable to current

> session_id();

When paypal sends ipn, i can change current session to previus session, and clear it.

```
session_id($_POST[custom]); 
session_start(); 
session_destroy(); //works fine
```

Comment: You need to provide more code.  Nothing about what you've posted would cause that problem.

Comment: I think there is no script, which can cause such problem. Because when i open that file dirrectly (i.e without post, and move unset out from if statement), it works fine.

Comment: Testing for `isset($_POST)` is pointless as it’s always true.

Comment: @Gumbo: Unless you explicitly `unset()` it. :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the IPN notification is not associated with the correct session.

The IPN is effectively a new session - it does not present the same session cookies that your client does, because you have not set them. Sessions are unique to a client, and the paypal gateway is a different client to that of your user.

You will need to bounce this information through a database. There is no sensible, easy way to have the IPN receiver directly modify the user's session data.

Comment: Sure, you are true. What you thinks, if i send my session id to paypal, and when it returns it back, i'll clear session associated with my session id ...

Comment: I don't think there is any way that you could do this. When you send something to Paypal, you are a client making a request and clients cannot set cookies on the server - that's not how cookies work, even if it was Paypal would probably ignore it for security purposes. Then during the IPN, Paypal is the client and you are the server, so it would send any cookies it has to you - but there is no way for you to set them, since it is effectively the start of a request chain every time. You will have to use a database and use the transaction/client/etc IDs to tie it up with the client's session.

Comment: @Syom If that works for you then you can use it and I won't stop you, but just be aware of the caveat: When a script is running, it has an exclusive lock on the session data (or more accurately, the session *file*). This means that any requests that are received while a script has the session open will block until the previous script has finished with the session data. You can work around this with `session_write_close()` - but use it wisely.

Answer (score 1):

You should be checking for a specific post variable.  $_POST will always be set, even if just an empty array.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['my_item']);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've already write the update, but it will be batter, if i write the solution as answer.

If i send session_id to paypal, and when it returns it back, i can set my current session to it's vallue, and delete it.

```
session_id($_POST[custom]); //$_POST[custom] is user's session id
session_start(); 
session_destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

Should your conditional be:

```
if(isset($_POST['ipn'])){
  ...do something
}
```

Then this should work:

```
if(isset($_POST['ipn'])){
  unset($_SESSION['my_item']);
}
```

Comment: That is not important. I've also tries to do the same without `if` statement.

Comment: hmm, your script looks ok - what do you see when you dump $_POST? what does that field and its content look like?